# Using same XAML for SL and WPF themes

Tags: wpf, silverlight, themes

I want to define control styles in a resource dictionary and use those for theming of Silverlight 4 **and** WPF 4 applications with as little adaption as possible.

Thats why I need to know all differences between SL and WPF theming, so that most of the XAML will work on both platforms with little to no changes.

The only difference that comes to my mind is using TargetType="Type" in Silverlight and TargetType="{x:Type Type}" in WPF. How about stuff like the VisualStateManager? Does the same vsm code work on both platforms? What other XAML parts may I have to change depending on platform?

Thanks,
Andre

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [WPF Compatibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903925(v=VS.95).aspx) topic in the documentation should cover some of your question.  However the differences are quite extensive and are beyond a simple answer.

Speaking very generally the Silverlight is a sub-set of WPF, however there at features which are implemented differently.

Probably your best way forward would be to target and test on Silverlight first then test on WPF.